# Как протестировать componentDidMount при помощи jest и enzyme, в котором вызывается функция не из props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, юнит-тесты, jest, enzyme

Подскажите, как можно протестировать данный компонент при помощи jest и enzyme.

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getCatalog()
  }

  getCatalog = async () => {
    try {
      const getApiData = await Axios.get(`${URL_GET}`)
      this.setState({
        data: getApiData.data,
        loading: false
      })
    } catch {
      this.setState({
        errorMsg: 'Ошибка при подключении'
      })
    }
  }
```

Необходимо протестировать метод `getCatalog`, заменив его `mock` функцией, но я не могу разобраться, как подменить родную функцию.

```
describe('App test componentDidMount', () => {
  const mockFetchGetCatalog = jest.fn()
  const props = {
    getCatalog: mockFetchGetCatalog
  }
  const AppContainer = shallow(<App {...props}/>)

  it('renders properly', () => {
    expect(AppContainer).toMatchSnapshot()
  })

  it('запрос на сервер', () => {
    expect(AppContainer).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) // создали ожидание с нужным ассертом
  })

})
```

так бы тест выглядел, если бы метод вызывался из пропсов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой подход должен сработать:

```
describe('Test componentDidMount', () => {
  // создать функцию-шпион на метод getCatalog для компонента App
  const spy = jest.spyOn(App.prototype, 'getCatalog');

  // монтритуем компонент App, а значит вызываем componentDidMount
  const wrapper = mount(<App />);

  // при этом можно явно вызвать метод: `wrapper.instance().getCatalog();`

  it('Method getCatalog have been called', () => {
    // во время вызова метода componentDidMount должен был вызваться getCatalog
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })   
})
```

Обращаю Ваше внимание на то, что [`shallow`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md) не вызывает `componentDidMount` и `componentDidUpdate`, поэтому нужно использовать [`mount`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md). Однако если предложенный вариант не сработает, то я предложу написать другой тест, в котором проверить вызов `componentDidMount`, а потом уже проверить вызов функции `getCatalog`, причем попробуем написать в двух разным методах. Однако при этом используем фугкцию-шпион не из `jest` а из `sinon`. Пример кода:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import App from './App';

describe('<App /> componentDidMount', () => {
  // ожидаем, что componentDidMount будет вызван один раз
  it('calls componentDidMount', () => {
    sinon.spy(App.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    expect(App.prototype.componentDidMount).to.have.property('callCount', 1);
  });
})

describe('<App /> getCatalog', () => {
  // ожидаем, что getCatalog будет вызван один раз
  it('calls getCatalog', () => {
    sinon.spy(App.prototype, 'getCatalog');
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    expect(App.prototype.getCatalog).to.have.property('callCount', 1);
  });
})
```

Если что-то не так работает, но пишите точки останова через `debugger;` и отлаживайте тест, всё должно работать, а если не работает, то значит что-то просто идет не так

Comment: увы, не работает)